# Sorting list using iterators won't sort last element C++

Tags: c++, list, sorting, stl, iterator

so I'm trying to sort a list of lists. Inside of each sublist the elements are classes that contains a runtime. This is the integer variable I am using to sort my list.

However, the list will not 100% sort itself if the smallest runtime is at the end of the list. I have a attached an image below of the terminal output for visualization.

Here is the code:

```
void sort( list<list<MetaData> > &omegaList )
{
// variables
list<list<MetaData> >::iterator cursor = omegaList.begin();
list<list<MetaData> >::iterator ptr    = omegaList.begin();
list<list<MetaData> >::iterator end    = omegaList.end();

// start the bubble sort...
for(; cursor != end; cursor++)
{
    // iterate through the list
    for(; ptr != end; ptr++)
    {
        // compare runtimes of different lists
        if( ptr->front().getProcessRunTime() < cursor->front().getProcessRunTime() )
            {
            // swap locations of lists in omegaList
            swap( *ptr, *cursor );
            // reset
            cursor = ptr = omegaList.begin();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the output:
[image: Output from running program.]

If anybody could please explain to me WHY it won't look at the very last element and then tell me how to fix it I would appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure where your bug is, but I think your *bubble sort* implementation is incorrect.

Comment: Eh, it was just more or less a "this is horribly inefficient like bubble sort so I'm just going to call it bubble sort."

Comment: Why are you not using `std::sort`?

Comment: Good question. I didn't know about it and I'm not sure how I would implement it given that I have a list of lists and it is the sublists that need to be sorted within the larger list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper way to do the sort is with [`std::list::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) as follows:

```
omegaList.sort(
    [](const list<MetaData>& lhs, const list<MetaData>& rhs) {
       return lhs.front().getProcessRunTime() <
              rhs.front().getProcessRunTime();
});
```

You can see that run [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fd4f8d32f56a6cf).

In your bubble sort, the reason your first element is not getting sorted is that as soon as you find an out-of-order element, you do this...

```
cursor = ptr = omegaList.begin();
```

...then the `ptr++` `for`-loop operation kicks in and your sorting therefore restarts at `begin() + 1`.  That `cursor = ptr = omegaList.begin();` is pretty wild - first O(n^3) sort implementation I've ever seen.

Comment: Nice, forgot that you can't use `std::sort` on `std::list`s

Comment: @Claudiu: be nice if it were specialised to call through to `std::list::sort`, but AFAIK that hasn't been done; I haven't thought through the implementation issues to know whether it's practical though.

Comment: Yeah. This is one of the many design decisions of C++ that saddens me - 99% of the time I'm doing `some_function(x.begin(), x.end(), ...)`, it would be cleaner IMO to do `some_function(x, ...)` instead. Especially relevant if `x` is anything but the shortest expression. And to your point, it would then allow `std::sort` to specialize through to `std::list::sort`.

Comment: @Claudiu: it's a longstanding, niggling hassle, but at least the [range proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4128.html) should fix it soonish.

Comment: Haha, glad I could surprise you and glad you could guide me on the correct path. I knew it was a bad algorithm (like really bad) but I'm more worried about getting this program written than how long it takes to execute. I was planning on rewriting it tomorrow via a better implementation but now you've shown me these gold mine. Thank you so much.